# Перехват и разбор трафика

Tags: html, http

*задача*: разобрать перехваченный трафик по содержимому html - страниц.

*вопрос такой*: каким образом можно представить трафик(перехваченный снифером) в виде отдельных html-страниц?

Чтобы потом написать приложение, которое будет читать эти странички и выдирать из них содержимое.

Comment: Где происходит перехват? Какой сниффер? Вы должны были дать ответы на эти вопросы в своем посте, автор.

В общем случае, http ответ сервера состоит из заголовков и тела. Так вот, именно в теле ответа и содержится искомый HTML.

Comment: перехват происходит прямо на локальной машине. Снифер не выбран пока, но как я понимаю, легче всего использовать wireshark. Собственно я впервые столкнулся с такой тематикой, поэтому плохо представляю как вообще происходит перехват. Прочитал статьи на вики, но все равно многое не понятно. Как я понял, сниферы выдают трафик в вде больших файлов(дампов) и вот из них надо как то вытащить html - страницы.
Буду очень признателен, если Вы меня поправите везде, где я заблуждаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то алгоритм такой:

1. Сниффером перехватываете `http` ответы сервера.
2. Если там `Content-type` в заголовках равен `text/html;` то берете тело из ответа и сохраняете куда вам нужно. Это и есть ваша html страница.